# How to solve such equation to obtain the CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the CDF of the following: $F_{Z}(z)=Pr(X-Y\leq z)$, where $Pr$ denotes the probability. Also i have the PDF of $X$ and $Y$. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the *joint* probability density function - or perhaps a conditional pdf.

$$\begin{align}\Pr(X\leqslant Y+z) &= \int_\Bbb R\int_{-\infty}^{y+z} f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex] &=\int_\Bbb R\int_{-\infty}^{y+z} f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex] &=\int_\Bbb R\int_{-\infty}^{y+z} f_{\small X}(x)f_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[3ex]\Pr(Y\geqslant X-z)&=\int_\Bbb R\int_{x-z}^\infty f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]\text{et cetera}&~~\lower{2ex}\ddots \end{align}$$

Unless, of course, the random variables are in fact independent.

$$\begin{align}\Pr(X\leqslant Y+z) &= \int_\Bbb R\int_{-\infty}^{y+z} f_{\small X}(x)f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[2ex] \Pr(Y\geqslant X-z)&= \int_\Bbb R\int_{x-z}^{\infty} f_{\small X}(x)f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

Comment: ok....and what will be the integration limit for integration over the real part...

Comment: $\Bbb R=(-\infty..\infty)$

Comment: I am getting stuck as PDF of both random variables $X$ and $Y$ is in terms of $x$. This is as shown: $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{\mu}}\exp({-\frac{x}{\sigma^2_{\mu}}})$ and $f_{Y}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{h}}\exp({-\frac{x}{\sigma^2_{h}}})$. Then in such case how to deal with this integration.

Comment: @charu $x$ is just a free variable.  You may substitute it with any other. Like so $$f_{\small Y}(y)=\tfrac 1{\sigma_h^2}\exp\left(\raise{0.5ex}{-\tfrac y{\sigma_h^2}}\right)$$Also, you should be sure to note the support for this function.  What is it?

Comment: both  $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ represents the PDF of exponential random variable. Also in the video lecture of Prof. Pillai, (available at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaLaw5xGlg8), the limit range is taken as from 0 to $z+y$, so which one is correct....

Comment: The final interval is the intersection of the joint support ($[0..\infty)^2$) and the constraint ($\{\langle x,y\rangle:x\leqslant y+z\}$). @charu $$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:  y\in[0..\infty)~\wedge~ x\in[0.. y+z]\}$$

Comment: Ok....got it....